# How to handle circular dependency when using PlayFramework and Guice?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I'm using PlayFramework 2.6 with Scala and Guice and I have the following design between my components:

Some `Person` class objects:

```
@Singleton
class Person1 @Inject() (personApiService: PersonApiService, personDBApiService: PersonDBApiService) extends Person {

  override def gerPersonInfo(person: Person): Future[PersonInfo] = {
    ...
  }

}
```

I have few of those (`Person1`, `Person2`...).

In `PersonService` I need a list of the people instances so I did this:

Created a trait:

```
trait PeopleManager {

  def application: Application

  def peopleList = List(
    classOf[Person1],
    classOf[Person2],
    ...
  )

  lazy val peopleInstances: List[Person] = peopleList.map(personClass => application.injector.instanceOf(personClass))
}
```

So now I can do:

```
class PersonService @Inject() (val application: Application) extends PeopleManager {
    // now I can use here peopleInstances.
}
```

The problem is, in my controller I get `PersonService` as dependency and I get to circular dependency. So in my controller I have to use `Provider` as suggested by PlayFramework documentation:

```
class MyController @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents, peopleService: Provider[PersonServcie]) extends AbstractController(cc) {
    ...
}
```

This solved the circular dependency issue, but I have a problem now in my tests to create a mock for `Provider[PersonService]`.

I feel something can be better in the design here that wont make me get circular dependency error, does someone have a nice suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what are `Person1`, `Person2`, etc. Could you explain that better. Also, why do you need a `PersonService` in those classes? Using the `app.injector` is also a bad smell. Why not injecting `Person1`, `Person2` directly?

Comment: @marcospereira `Person1`, `Person2` etc are some objects I have of type Person, they are classes and they have Injected dependencies. at some point of my app I  need to have a list of those classes so I can iterate on them, so in my example i have `PersonService ` but it dosent really matter, I agree that using `app.injector` is a bad smell, id love to get a better suggestion :)

Comment: If you for some reason needs to have the circular dependency, then using the provider is the way to go. How are you trying to mock it?